# htaccess 301 redirect with exeception for one link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

So i'm trying to find a way to do a 301 redirect from old domain to new domain.
But i'd like to ignore 1 url that should not be redirected

I usually use something like this to do a 301 redirect

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain2.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

What additional rule can i add to this to ignore redirect for url : domain1.com/a/b/

how should I insert it in my htaccess ?

Old domain : Domain1.com

New domain : Domain2.com

Ignored url in redirect : domain1.com/a/b/

My htaccess looks like this :

```
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
# Modified Time: 22-12-20 13:37:50
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/domain1\.com\/$1 [R=301,L]
# Start WPFC Exclude
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=domain1
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|WP_FASTEST_CACHE_CSS_VALIDATOR|Twitterbot|LinkedInBot|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(WP\sFastest\sCache\sPreload(\siPhone\sMobile)?\s*Bot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /home/admin/web/domain1.com/public_html/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "index\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache












# BEGIN LBCWpFastestCache
<FilesMatch "\.(webm|ogg|mp4|ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|otf|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType video/webm A10368000
ExpiresByType video/ogg A10368000
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A10368000
ExpiresByType image/webp A10368000
ExpiresByType image/gif A10368000
ExpiresByType image/png A10368000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A10368000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A10368000
ExpiresByType image/ico A10368000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A10368000
ExpiresByType text/css A10368000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-truetype A10368000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Expires "max-age=A10368000, public"
Header unset ETag
Header set Connection keep-alive
FileETag None
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END LBCWpFastestCache
# BEGIN FRedirect_ErrorDocument
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN FRedirect_ErrorDocument" and "END FRedirect_ErrorDocument" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
# END FRedirect_ErrorDocument
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What additional rule can i add to this htaccess file to ignore redirect for url : domain1.com/a/b/

Answer (score 1):

To exclude a  link from the redirection, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a/b/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain2.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer
So i tried your method but i think i just don't know how to insert it properly in the htaccess.
When i do it, it either doesn't ignore the url or i get 404 error message on the ignored url.

I edited my post now to show my actual htaccess.

Comment: @Mk1 This rule should be at the top of your htaccess before other rules.  If it still doesn't work then try clearing your browser cache or use a different browser to test the redirect.

Comment: Yeah i tried that but only the full redirection works. the excluded url is still redirecting to new domain

Comment: @Mk1 What is the URL?